# Как яндекс распознаёт, что запрос делается не из браузера?

Tags: php, бот, get, яндекс-музыка

Делаю такой запрос:

```
$opts = array('http'=>array('method'=>"GET",'header'=>"Cookie:*****"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
echo file_get_contents("https://music.yandex.ru/handlers/music-search.jsx?text=Aviici&type=tracks", false, $context);
```

Где `*****` - это мои куки, которые я выловил в браузере, но в ответ я получаю location на страницу как на картинке ниже, а должен получить треки.

По запросу Aviici в json формате.

Как яндекс распознаёт, что запрос делается не из браузера?

**P.s:** Если же открываю этот URL в браузере, то все нормально, пользуюсь denwer так, что у меня, и у сервера 1 IP.

**P.s.s:** Данный запрос не является запросом к API, так как у яндекс музыки нет API.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов куча. Может быть на User-Agent смотрят, а может еще что-то.

Опять же не совсем ясно - скрипт у вас локально запускается или же с хостинга. Если с хостинга, то вероятней всего IP хостинга уже в черном списке Яндекса.

Хотя есть у меня подозрение, что вы просто "подзамучили" их своими запросами и они блокируют связку User-Agent и IP.

Как таковой проверки на ботов я не вижу. Указанный URL открывается с помощью curl без проблем.

UPDATE: попробовал несколько раз запросить этот url с помощью curl. Где-то на пятой попытке получил перенаправление на страницу. Так что думаю основной принцип определения бота: много одинаковых запросов, с небольшим промежутком между запросами и при этом User-Agent не похож на браузер.